# How to automaically position an inline svgs into a navbar?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have drew few vector illustrations with inkscape.

Now i'm trying to position those svgs into a vertical navbar.
I'd like to position each illustration into it's corresponding place (using inline SVG).
I have read [css-tricks: scale-svg](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/) which was quite useful for me,
but would like to avoid inserting the position manually for each illustrated icon (it seems wrong!),

```
<li>
      <!-- I don't think this is the correct approach, how should i do it? -->
      <svg viewBox="-150 -150 300 300" class="first-icon">
          <use href="#my-smiley"/>
      </svg>
</li>
```

This is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/Codingforpleasure/pen/zbqWzK?editors=1100),

Can somebody suggest a proper way? and demonstrate?

Any example will be great!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of steps to achieve the effect that you have with font-awesome icons and have them on your own hand made svg icons:

1. I would suggest having your `viewBox` attribute set to a bounding box that includes just your graphics without any padding and leave the positioning of the resulting icon to css styles.
2. Since you have other icons wrapped in `<a>` and `<i>` tags, you can do the same for the svg icons for consistency sake.
3. Your font-awesome icons use implicit font size of 14px. Since the svg icon is not text, we can't use `font-size`, but rather we will use explicit `width` and `height`
4. Your `:hover` effect uses text scaling, and as shown above, it would only have an effect on font based icons. Since your icon is svg, it is better to use generic `transform: scale(value)` rule, which would work both on font and on icon. Please note, that we want to scale the icon, and not the anchor, so I changed the rule to work on `<i>` elements instead of `<a>` elements.
5. To make the svg icon have the correct scale center, we need to play a bit with `transform-origin` rule.

With all that changes your code should look something like [this forked codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZedPK)

Answer (score 1):

For clarity I've simplified your example:

This is how I would do it: I would draw the symbol with the center in the point {0,0}. The width and the height of the symbol's `viewBox` are 300 units, the same as the width and the height of the `.first-icon` `viewBox`

```css
svg.first-icon{width:90vh;border:1px solid}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 300" class="first-icon">
  <use href="#my-smiley"/>
</svg>

<svg>
  <symbol viewBox="-150 -150 300 300" id="my-smiley">
  <g stroke="#f7931e">
    <circle  r="50" fill="gray" stroke-width=".004"/>
    <g transform="translate(-145,-80)">
    <path d="M144.59 64.536l-10.606 4.22-2.537 11.128-7.29-8.783-11.368 1.027 6.1-9.648-4.489-10.494 11.06 2.82 8.594-7.511.735 11.39zM184.32 63.824l-10.606 4.22-2.537 11.128-7.29-8.783-11.368 1.027 6.1-9.648-4.489-10.494 11.06 2.82 8.594-7.511.735 11.39z" fill="#f7931e" stroke-width=".002"/>
    <path fill="#ffd5d5" stroke-width=".004" d="M122.46 102.72h48.381v5.292H122.46z"/>
  </g>
  </g>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

If you want you can make the `<symbol>` smaller, but then you need to give the `<use>` a `width` a `height`, an `x` and an `y` attributes:

```css
svg:first-of-type{width:90vh; border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 300" class="first-icon">
  <use x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100" href="#my-smiley"/>
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <symbol viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" id="my-smiley" class="my-smiley">
  <g id="kk" stroke="#f7931e">
    <circle  r="50" fill="gray" stroke-width=".004"/>
    <g transform="translate(-145,-80)">
    <path d="M144.59 64.536l-10.606 4.22-2.537 11.128-7.29-8.783-11.368 1.027 6.1-9.648-4.489-10.494 11.06 2.82 8.594-7.511.735 11.39zM184.32 63.824l-10.606 4.22-2.537 11.128-7.29-8.783-11.368 1.027 6.1-9.648-4.489-10.494 11.06 2.82 8.594-7.511.735 11.39z" fill="#f7931e" stroke-width=".002"/>
    <path fill="#ffd5d5" stroke-width=".004" d="M122.46 102.72h48.381v5.292H122.46z"/>
  </g>
  </g>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```